# Is it possible to do something similiar to RPA using windows command prompt?

Tags: automation, rpa

I need to automate a few tasks (data extraction, activating applications etc.) However, I cannot use any external automation software such as UiPath. Is there any inbuilt alternative I can use such as windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

It was created so those tasks could be automated. you could use python to do most of those tasks, but none of the built in software will do that for you.